# Can I read a memory buffer from different threads without any lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

Assume that I have a memory buffer that different threads wants to read it (so no change to it) Do I need a lock to protect it from concurrent read?

I know that for writing, we should make sure that only one thread can write to it, but what is the situation on read?

To clarify, the buffer is a table that several threads may read it and use it, but it is a constant table that is read from disk at the start of program and before any thread starts.

So things happens in this way:

1. Program Starts
2. Program reads table values from disk.
3. Program create threads and pass the data to them.
4. Different threads process data by reading this table and some other data and generate some data, but no thread change this table.
5. Program finishes.

Comment: Something must be writing to that buffer, else it wouldn't contain anything.worth reading.

Comment: If the memory buffer was completely written before the threads were created, then no lock/memory-barrier is needed.

Comment: If you know there are (and will not ever be) any writers - that is; the data is static. Then no, you don't need any locks. But *if* the data may ever change, then you *do* need locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume that I have a memory buffer that different threads wants to read it (so no change to it) Do I need a lock to protect it from concurrent read?

As long as you are doing this reading after the buffer was populated then no, you don't need any synchronization.  As long as you are only reading from the same object you do not need synchronization.

You only need synchronization when you have one or more writers trying to modify an object or if you have one or more writers trying to modify an object and one ore more readers trying to read its value.

Comment: Writes might not be visible by, say, other cores in a multicore processor if there's no cache coherence.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads are reading the buffer, and none are writing to it, then concurrent read is generally not a problem.    For example, if the buffer is populated before the threads are created, and never changed, then reads can be concurrent without a lock.

If any threads are modifying the buffer, then a lock is necessary both for reading and writing.   This is necessary to prevent the writes interfering with reads as well as writes - for example, prevent a situation in which the buffer is read while partially written.

Answer (score -1):

> Do I need a lock to protect it from concurrent read?

No.

But if there were writes made *earlier* than your threads, then, depending on the machine you're on - the later reads may return different values.

Comment: How would that be possible ?

Comment: @LWimsey: Non-cache-coherent architectures. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) on Wikipedia - that's quite some overhead. On some multi-core processors (not to mention multi-socket), some cache levels are not kept coherent; so a recent write on one core might not propagate all the way back to actual RAM and then invalidate the lower-level caches on other cores which then read from that address.

Comment: Interesting perspective, but it would violate the C++ standards requirement that memory operations sequenced before thread creation are visible inside the thread itself (N4713, par. 33.3.2.2-6 [thread constructors])
On a platform with no cache coherency, an incoherent memory view is possible (a load returning a stale value), but not after synchronization.

Comment: @LWimsey: I was actually thinking about when the threads already exist during the writes.